# Create a toggle button to hide rows of one sheet based on cell values of another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two Excel sheets "Summary" and "Proposal Units". I want row 12 in the Summary sheet to hide based on the R12 value in the Proposal Units sheet. The same applies to all rows between 12-27 in the Summary sheet based on the  value in cells (R: 27,59,72,76,122,136,222,231,302,322,329,367,450,467,482,493) in the Proposal Units sheet. I am using the following code that just shows the toggle and the first row of 12 in Summary sheet and cell R12 in Proposal Units sheet. No action has occurred when I ran this just to test it.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Intersect(Target, Range("R12:R493")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = ("$R$12") And Target.Value = "NO" Then
        Sheets("Summary").Row("11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Address = ("$R$12") And Target = "YES" Then
        Sheets("Summary").Row("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spot the difference... you'll kick yourself when you see it...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim n As Integer

If Intersect(Target, Range("R12:R493")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Data").Range("A1") = Target.Row
n = Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Value


If Target.Address = ("$R$12") And Target.Value = "NO" Then
    Sheets("Summary").Rows("n").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Target.Address = ("$R$12") And Target = "YES" Then
    Sheets("Summary").Rows("n").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You need to use "Rows" not "Row"

EDIT:
You need to create another sheet called "Data" (or whatever, just update the formula and macro)
Leave cell A1 blank, in cell A2 add the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

Then in column C list the Target row number, and in column D list the row numbers that need to be hidden

Comment: Wow I am kicking myself on the difference of just that! In coding for all of the cells I need in column R of sheet "Proposal units", would I just copy this for each cell and row to be hidden in sheet "summary"? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: It would be quicker to define the row number as "n" and have a reference sheet with 2 columns that have the target row and the row to hide.  I will update my answer